# Trying to scrape table data from a <script> function embedded in a website

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the table from the following website: https://www.corelogic.com.au/our-data/recent-sales?postcode=5600

Using BeautifulSoup and attempting to 'find' the 'table' returns a NoneType because the table itself actually appears to be a script function that is pulling 90 random records from a secured dataset...

I've tried the following:

```
url = "https://www.corelogic.com.au/our-data/recent-sales?postcode=5600"

oururl= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(oururl)

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='function decodeEntities(encodedString)').text)
print(data)
```

However, I just receive a 403 error.
Can anyone help me to inspect and pull the freely available 90 records from this site's table?

Answer (score 0):

You are close to your goal and could extract the data and store it in a dataframe like:

```
import json, requests, re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.corelogic.com.au/our-data/recent-sales?postcode=5600'

jsonData = json.loads(re.search(r'postcodeData = (.*?});', requests.get(url).text).group(1))
pd.DataFrame(jsonData['data'][0]['properties'])
```